# Is asking for camera, media or file permission considered collection of data?

Tags: android, android-studio, app-store, policy

I don't understand if this is considered collection of data or not, for example I ask for file permission on my app but its for the purpose of the user to view his files in my app, but I don't know or can't see what his viewing and ask for file permission with the only purpose of him viewing his files in my app is that considered collection of data according to google play console policy?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be considered data collection as long as you are not sharing the file data to your server or other sources.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).